# Conditional behaviours in a jQuery powered menu

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

One day on from my first question, I'm afraid to say I'm back. A different problem this time though...

I have a horizontal menu with some nested menus as below:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="mainNav">
        <li><a href="expand-the-sub-menu">Option 1</a>
            <ul id="option1Nav">
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 1 Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 1 Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 1 Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 1 Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 1 Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="expand-the-sub-menu">Option 2</a>
            <ul id="option2Nav">
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 2 Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 2 Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 2 Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 2 Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="somewhere">Option 2 Link 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="somewhere">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="somewhere">Option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="somewhere">Option 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="somewhere">Option 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[CraftyFella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30317/craftyfella) helped [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970702/making-jquery-display-the-correct-sub-menu-when-present) in getting basic behaviours working, but I'd like to expand on this to include conditional behaviours based on the current menu state.

The (commented) logic and code so far is as follows:

```
$('#mainNav ul').hide();
$('#mainNav>li>a').click(function(){
    var elem = this;
    // If clicked element has a sibling ul with specified class
    if($(elem).next().hasClass("navChild")){

        // & If another child ul is already visible
        if ($('.navChild').is(':visible')){

            // Fade out any others, and fade this one in
            $(this).fadeOut(300, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
                $(elem).next("ul").fadeIn(300,'easeOutQuint');
            });
            return false;

        // Else if no child ul is visible
        }else{

            // Raise main links and fade in current child ul
            $('nav').animate({bottom:'60px'},300,'easeOutQuint',function(){
                $(elem).next().fadeIn(300,'easeOutQuint');
            });
        }

    // Else clicked element has no sibling ul with specified class
    }else{
        // If others are visible, fade them out and lower the main links
        $('#mainNav ul').fadeOut(300, 'easeOutQuint',function(){
            $('nav').animate({bottom:'24px'},300,'easeOutQuint');
        });
    }
});
```

In brief: all sub-menus should be hidden, they should be shown/swapped if present as a clicked sibling, or all hidden if not.

Sadly, it doesn't quite work, it almost does except the "swapping" part - if a sub-menu is already visible, and another is triggered to show, both end up being shown, and the clicked element disappears(!).

It's probably awful code too - I am still very new to this - but if someone could help with the logic part, I can attend to cleaning things up later on.

EDIT - http://jsfiddle.net/hKYJz/1/ - now bizarrely not working at all >:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working finally. Thanks to those who contributed - I'd almost certainly still be stuck by now without your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/hKYJz/47/

Answer (score 1):

try to implement using this

```
$('#mainNav ul').hide();
$('#mainNav>li').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
       $('#mainNav ul').fadeOut(300);
    $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(300);
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, that's almost there except for the movement of <nav> to accommodate the extra elements. One other question - why do you only target the #mainNav>li elements?

Comment: @verism in dropDowns we generally make the whole li clickable

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$('#mainNav ul').hide();
$('#mainNav>li').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var elm = this;
    $('nav').animate({
                bottom:'60px',
                duration:300,
                easing:'easeOutQuint'
            },function(){  
                    $(elm).find('ul').fadeIn(300);
            });
    $('#mainNav ul').fadeOut(300);
});
```

This is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hKYJz/35/

Comment: Thank you for this - it's so close to what I'm aiming for. The only missing action is sending the <nav> back down if no sub-menus are open. But again, thanks so much for this - I can't believe how convoluted my attempt was. Edit - also just noticed that the menu rises even when a sub-menu isn't present.